# Can't get multiple poly lines to display in google map code

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, lidar, lidar-data

[Image of the current output. I want this to display the polylines as previous data points of where each object has been in past frames.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1eN1.jpg)I'm using the library's gmplot and geographiclib.Geodesic to attempt to track objects in a LIDAR payload. The goal is to get an output every iteration of the payload to get a google map graph that shows each object in the payload with the most recent position labeled with the object's ID as well as having a marker showing where it is in latitude and longitude coordinates. In another file, I have an algorithm that uses the x and y coordinates within the LIDAR to determine the correct latitude and
longitude of the objects. Getting the marker correct is working.

We have all of the data inside of a JSON file where we have the latitude, longitude, and object ID's listed
and indexed by frame. A nested dictionary is being used to hold this data, so that makes the functions in
the code easier to read. All of the functions are put together in the function at the bottom of the code called
live_graph_coordinates.

The issue comes in when I try to get the polylines to be tracked behind all previous data points of the
objects. I use a dictionary to track all previous points of latitude and longitude for their respective ID
value, but I'm having trouble getting these to display correctly as well as split into multiple polylines.
Does anyone have experience in this library or know anyone who could possibly give a solution to this
problem?

```
# Imports all modules needed for the code
import json
import gmplot
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
import gmaps
from math import atan2, degrees, sqrt
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import os
geod = Geodesic.WGS84

def parse_json(filename):
    # returns list of json objects
    # list to hold every string version of each JSON object in separate list within the larger list
    split_list = [[]]
    # for iterating which JSON object the string is currently being added to
    i = 0
    # opens JSON file with name file
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file.readlines():
            # not the end of the JSON object
            if "}," in line:
                split_list[i].append(line)
                continue
            # is the end of the JSON object
            elif "}" in line:
                # adds the last line of the object to the string
                split_list[i].append(line)
                # goes to the next list
                i += 1
                split_list.append([])
                continue
            # just another part of the string
            else:
                split_list[i].append(line)
    # list of strings that're each JSON objects
    json_string_list = []
    # iterates over each list from above
    for i in split_list:
        # creates empty string to convert each to
        json_string = ""
        for j in i:
            json_string += j
        # appends the string once it's fully made to the list of JSON objects
        json_string_list.append(json_string)
    return json_string_list[-2:]


def get_JSON_dict(json_string_list, previous_lat_lng):
    # returns x, y lists
    json_string_list = json_string_list[0].split("}],")
    # adds the }]} back to the the string in each list
    for index, stripped_string in enumerate(json_string_list):
        add_back = stripped_string + "}]}"
        # adds the string back into the list
        json_string_list[index] = add_back
    # takes out the empty string at index -
    json_string_list.pop(-1)
    # iterates over the entire JSON string object
    for s in json_string_list:
        # loads the JSON string as a JSON object
        if "{" != s[0]:
            d = "{" + s
            json_s = json.loads(d)
        else:
            json_s = json.loads(s)
        # finds the frames as keys and iterates over them
        for key in json_s.keys():
            # iterates over the list within the keys variable
            for index, obj in enumerate(json_s[key]):
                # splits the string list into an actual list
                latitude = obj["latitude"]
                longitude = obj["longitude"]
                # checks whether or not the ID is already in the dictionary
                # if not then it doesn't add it to the dictionary again
                if obj["id"] in previous_lat_lng:
                    # ID is already in the dictionary (doesn't need to be added)
                    pass
                else:
                    # sets it equal to an empty list to hold latitude and longitude values respectively
                    previous_lat_lng[obj["id"]] = []
                # changes the dictionary to have floats instead of string values for the positions
                json_s[key][index]["latitude"] = latitude
                json_s[key][index]["longitude"] = longitude
    # returns the JSON dictionary
    return json_s, previous_lat_lng


def update_dict(lat, lon, previous_lat_lng, id):
    # checks whether or not the ID is already within the dictionary
    if id in previous_lat_lng.keys():
        # appends the current coordinates to the dictionary
        previous_lat_lng[id].append([lat, lon])
    else:
        # creates a 2D list with the new coordinates in the dictionary
        previous_lat_lng[id] = [[lat, lon]]
    return previous_lat_lng


def graph_data(json_dictionary, cam_lat, cam_lng, frame, previous_lat_lng, color="red", color2="cornflowerblue", edge_width=2.5):
    # creates the map plotter
    gmap3 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(cam_lat, cam_lng, 20)
    for i in range(len(json_dictionary["Frame " + str(frame)])):
        # gets the current latitude and longitude
        latitude = float(json_dictionary["Frame " + str(frame)][i]["latitude"])
        longitude = float(json_dictionary["Frame " + str(frame)][i]["longitude"])
        # finds the current id to put into the previous_lat_lng dictionary
        current_id = json_dictionary["Frame " + str(frame)][i]["id"]
        # updates the previous_lat_lng dictionary to be able to be used in the graphing function
        previous_lat_lng = update_dict(latitude, longitude, previous_lat_lng, current_id)

    for id in previous_lat_lng.keys():
        # creates a list to be plotted on the map
        lat_list, lng_list = [], []
        for l in previous_lat_lng[id]: # l is a list of coordinates [latitude, longitude]
            # adds the latitude coordinate
            lat_list.append(l[0])
            # adds the longitude coordinate
            lng_list.append(l[1])
    # plots the line of where the person traveled
    gmap3.plot(lat_list, lng_list, color, edge_width, title=id)
    gmap3.marker(lat_list[-1], lng_list[-1], color2, title=id)

    # changes the directory to save the map to a separate folder within the project folder
    os.chdir("maps")
    # draws the google map and saves it to the map folder
    gmap3.draw("map" + str(frame) + ".html")
    # changes the directory back 1 folder to prevent errors
    os.chdir("..")
    # returns the previous dictionary in order to keep the previous data stored
    return previous_lat_lng


def live_graph_coordinates(latitude, longitude, json_file, frame, previous_lat_lng):
    # Uses api key to be able to make the coordinates
    gmaps.configure(**api key is here**)

    # shows the maps in satellite vision
    gmaps.figure('SATELLITE')

    # parses the json file to get a list of strings which are each a JSON object
    json_string_list = parse_json(json_file)

    # gets a list of x and y values for every object in the list
    json_dictionary, previous_lat_lng = get_JSON_dict(json_string_list, previous_lat_lng)

    if json_dictionary != None:
        # Graphs all the data points from the JSON file
        previous_lat_lng = graph_data(json_dictionary, latitude, longitude, frame, previous_lat_lng)
        return previous_lat_lng
    else:
        # no objects detected
        pass
```

```
{"Frame 1": [{"id": 533, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48799308670221, "longitude": -111.90885153944437}, {"id": 549, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48801292738194, "longitude": -111.90885868765811}, {"id": 673, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48804833314041, "longitude": -111.90882281530168}, {"id": 680, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4880037031338, "longitude": -111.90886720421587}, {"id": 682, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48801928916118, "longitude": -111.90877697851846}, {"id": 686, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48804053863665, "longitude": -111.90881977666776}, {"id": 687, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.4880341240495, "longitude": -111.90881708982506}, {"id": 691, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48803122508181, "longitude": -111.9088324527267}, {"id": 693, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48804587402998, "longitude": -111.90883551218909}, {"id": 694, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48803580008242, "longitude": -111.90882961435683}, {"id": 696, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48802004624938, "longitude": -111.90881496775653}, {"id": 697, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48802187886198, "longitude": -111.90882847417957}, {"id": 698, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48801766538075, "longitude": -111.90882289307378}, {"id": 706, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4881289113697, "longitude": -111.908896469379}, {"id": 707, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48806293756819, "longitude": -111.90880008535265}, {"id": 710, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4880314185434, "longitude": -111.90878311481961}, {"id": 711, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48804442683758, "longitude": -111.90879309453386}, {"id": 714, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.488061420726034, "longitude": -111.90879962024852}, {"id": 715, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.488055189955865, "longitude": -111.90879724325653}], 
"Frame 2": [{"id": 533, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48799308670221, "longitude": -111.90885153944437}, {"id": 549, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48801292738194, "longitude": -111.90885868765811}, {"id": 673, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48804833314041, "longitude": -111.90882281530168}, {"id": 680, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4880037031338, "longitude": -111.90886720421587}, {"id": 682, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48801928916118, "longitude": -111.90877697851846}, {"id": 686, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48804053863665, "longitude": -111.90881977666776}, {"id": 687, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.4880341240495, "longitude": -111.90881708982506}, {"id": 691, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48803122508181, "longitude": -111.9088324527267}, {"id": 693, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48804587402998, "longitude": -111.90883551218909}, {"id": 694, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48803580008242, "longitude": -111.90882961435683}, {"id": 696, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48802004624938, "longitude": -111.90881496775653}, {"id": 697, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48802187886198, "longitude": -111.90882847417957}, {"id": 698, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48801766538075, "longitude": -111.90882289307378}, {"id": 706, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4881289113697, "longitude": -111.908896469379}, {"id": 707, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.48806293756819, "longitude": -111.90880008535265}, {"id": 710, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.4880314185434, "longitude": -111.90878311481961}, {"id": 711, "classification": "UNKNOWN", "latitude": 33.48804442683758, "longitude": -111.90879309453386}, {"id": 714, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.488061420726034, "longitude": -111.90879962024852}, {"id": 715, "classification": "PERSON", "latitude": 33.488055189955865, "longitude": -111.90879724325653}],
```

```
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3119",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3218",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3492",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3493",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3236",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3483",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912);
        var img = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/home/greg/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gmplot/markers/6495ED.png');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: "3119",
        icon: img,
        position: latlng
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

var PolylineCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487887, -111.909013),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488226, -111.908717),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487970, -111.908849),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488199, -111.908902),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.488194, -111.908912),
new google.maps.LatLng(33.487842, -111.908994),
];
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON file that demonstrates your issue? Can you draw multiple polylines on the map directly?

Comment: I added an example of the first 2 frames from the JSON file. My coworker says he's gotten multiple polylines drawn on the map directly before. I'll see if I can get the code for it and put it in here.

Comment: That would be my question.  How does the code that "works" compare to your code that doesn't seem to work.  I see examples that put multiple polylines on the map, but hard to compare those with your code.

Comment: What does one of the .html files look like (redact your API key)?  Actually, looking at the posted code, you have already made that public, so redacting it now won't help; delete that one and create a new one.

Comment: I made those changes, thank you I didn't catch that I had left the API key in. The output of the image is what the most recent working code is, however the map is displaying incorrectly.

Comment: The html output would be more useful than a picture (at least to me). It also isn't clear what the issue is.  What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I added the html code at the bottom as well now. The issue is in the image, all of the polylines are connected, that's not what the polylines are meant for. The lines should be following behind where the objects have traveled. For example if they've only been tracked for 2 meters north, then it should show a marker 2 meters from where they were detected at, with a 2-meter polyline trailing behind it. As of now, the polylines decided to connect to all other objects in the frame.

Comment: In the html you posted, all the points in the polylines are the same, and there is only one marker.  Is that expected?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a file that I'm not sure why I still had, I added a different code snippet. This was a smaller part of a 4000 line HTML file with all the objects like this if you'd like I can add more than the lines I added in.

Comment: Right now, your code is somewhat complicated, which makes it hard for people here to help. The following are intended as general comments that will improve the quality of your code -- they may well not help wit the problem at hand:
- you should definitely not hand-roll your own JSON parsing. Use the `json` library

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/358069/115

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are confusing two libraries:

- https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot, a somewhat unmaintained library that generates an HTML representation of a map
- https://github.com/pbugnion/gmaps, a library for drawing data on Google maps in Jupyter notebooks, based on Jupyter widgets.

It's not clear what you're trying to do, but these packages are not inter-operable.

With `gmaps`, you should be able to update polylines on a map. I'd suggest looking into the following pages:
- [this](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#drawing-markers-lines-and-polygons) on drawing poly-lines
- [this](https://jupyter-gmaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app_tutorial.html#updating-symbols-in-response-to-other-widgets) page on updating a symbol. You should be able to convert that to polylines.

---

As a side-note, right now, your code is somewhat complicated, which makes it hard for people here to help. You'll get better quality answers if you try to come up with a simple, reproducible example.

Separately, you should definitely not hand-roll your own JSON parsing. Use the `json` library. If you only want to half-parse the JSON (it looks like that's what you're doing), parse everything, then re-dump what you need. Parsing is hard. Don't do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped miles. I didn't even realize that the maps library wasn't being used as I named the plotter gmap3 which makes it confusing that I was actually using gmplot. I went back and fixed all these issues and have it working finally. Thank you!